# Is SoundCloud HTML5 Widget broken in Internet Explorer? Will not play sounds. Visible But Play Button has no effect

Tags: api, soundcloud

Link to demonstrate the bug:

http://www.multitask123.com/fmgem/SCIEBug.htm

While testing my production site I noticed that the SoundCloud HTML5 widget no longer is playing sounds. It is visible but both autoplay and clicking the manual orange play button have no effect in Internet Explorer version 8, 9 & 10. I have tested this on multiple machines over the past several hours.

If you pull up my linked page in Chrome, FF or Safari it will play the sound. 
IE... Not so much as in not at all.

Thanks!!

UPDATE: The original link started working but now it does NOT. After much testing I have narrowed it down to the actual sounds the page attempts to play:

These sounds play in IE 9 & 10

http://www.fmgem.com/Gemmies.html?username=Lanza&vid=tracks/65749367&ts=1381112340930

http://www.fmgem.com/Gemmies.html?username=buddyholly&vid=tracks/73239319&ts=1381105260378

These sounds do NOT play in IE 9 & 10

http://www.fmgem.com/Gemmies.html?username=Lanza&vid=tracks/56193332&ts=1381079400115

http://www.fmgem.com/Gemmies.html?username=Lanza&vid=tracks/41201398&ts=1381114200843

I reached out to help@soundcloud.com and will post back with the outcome.

Comment: I've just come across this problem myself. I noticed it on a site I was building for a client but soon realised it affected all sites that used the HTML5 player embedded. 
It only seems to affect the HTML5 player (the flash player is fine) in Internet Explorer. I've tested it in IE8-10 and all are affected. The play button works in Internet Explorer with an empty cache, but from the 2nd play onwards it refuses to play the track (i.e. the play button doesn't work). No word from SoundCloud yet with this one.

Comment: Best thing to do is reach out to them by email. They are very friendly and willing to work through the problem. I believe the email is: support@soundcloud.com If I am not mistaken. You will need to supply some type of link to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks. I am in touch with them on Twitter, but agree that opening a ticket by email is the best way. Did you get an answer from them on this? I was glad when I realised it wasn't me going mad and other people had seen the issue with IE.

Comment: This bug is still active and I have reached out to help@soundcloud.com - The issue seems to be the actual sound attempting to be played. I am updating the post with links to illustrate.

Comment: I have just discovered a problem with Internet explorer v10. I was looking through various artists and noticed that only about half the songs listed would play. I have noticed this before and had put it down to a temporary problem with servers at soundcloud. What I have discovered now is that it is a problem with Explorer. I use different browsers on different machines and that is why the problem only showed on occasions. I did a bit of investigating and found the problem is when a song or set is set to widget disabled. If the widget is disabled the song plays fine in both Firefox and Chrome,

Answer (score 1):

Something that might help SoundCloud team, you can reproduce this problem on their sample Widget Page.

https://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets

Using IE10
When the page first load, The Bugle will play fine when you click the play button. 
Reload the page (F5 or Ctrl-F5)
Try to play the same audio again.

If you close all instances of IE, and try again it will work the first time.

The good news is IE11 doesn't seem to have this problem.